# tracepoint with different signature

Tags: trace, lttng

I want to insert lttng - tracepoint("traceprovider_name"tracepoint_name" "$1"$2") statements **with same tracepoint_name and traceprovider_name** but want to use **different tracepoint signature** in the code: for example:

```
    TRACEPOINT_EVENT( 
    provider_name_test, 
    tp_name_tp, 
    TP_ARGS( 
    int, my_integer_arg, char*, my_string_arg 
    ), 
    TP_FIELDS( 
    ctf_string(my_string_field, my_string_arg) 
    ctf_integer(int, my_integer_field, my_integer_arg)

    ) 
    )

------------------------------------------------------------------------

    with the above defined traceprovider I can use: 
     tracepoint(provider_name_test, tp_name_tp,23, "hi there")

    I want tracepoint() signatures as below 

    tracepoint(provider_name_test, tp_name_tp,23  )

    tracepoint(provider_name_test, tp_name_tp,"hi there" )
```

Comment: Did you have a look at http://lttng.org/docs/#doc-tracing-your-own-user-application and the more comprehensive http://lttng.org/docs/#doc-c-application?

Comment: Yes I did go through it , could not find the it may be I am missing something here

Comment: What's your real question here? You're asking to write the whole file for you. Perhaps you're having difficulties with one aspect of tracepoint provider definitions? Besides, please format your question appropriately using Markdown; it's hard to read.

Comment: No not the whole file I just want to know how to declare TP_ARGS( ) TP_FIELDS( ) if I wish only to use few arguments in the tracepoint ( ) at different times. With same traceprovider name and tracepoint name. So I can associate them to one event later –

Answer (score 0):

The traceprovider name and tracepoint name have to unique in order to maintain fine granularity required for root cause analysis.So it should be unique but you can use the same tracepoints in multiple places.